# Python: My return variable is always None

Tags: python, recursion, return

So I found a strange thing that happens in python whenever I try to return an optional parameter or at least I think that is why it is happening.

Here is my code

```
def reverse(string, output = ""):
    if string == "":
        print "winner: ", output
        return output
    output = output + string[-1]
    string = string[:-1]
    reverse(string, output=output)
```

And here is what happens when I run it:

```
>>> output = reverse("hello")
winner:  olleh
>>> print output
None
```

Anyone know why my return is always None?

Comment: Your function has no return value for anything other than the input `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the return value of the recursive call.

```
def reverse(string, output = ""):
    if string == "":
        print "winner: ", output
        return output
    output = output + string[-1]
    string = string[:-1]
    return reverse(string, output=output)
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't think about having to go back out of my recursion with the return statement. It makes sense though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(string, output = ""):
    if string == "":
        print ("winner: ", output)
        return output
    output = output + string[-1]
    string = string[:-1]
    return reverse(string, output=output)
def main():
    reverse("hello")
main()
```

OR

```
def reverse(string, output = ""):
    if string == "":
        print ("winner: ", output)
        return output
    output = output + string[-1]
    string = string[:-1]
    return reverse(string, output=output)
reverse("hello")
```

OUTPUT FOR BOTH

```
>>> 
winner:  olleh
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
winner:  olleh
>>>
```